# Update SQL with Inner Join in Prestashop in DB

Tags: mysql, database, sql-update, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I try to update the quantity in a Prestashop table. I have an INNER JOIN to get the upc from the table "ps_product_attribute"

```
UPDATE ps_stock_available
SET ps_stock_available.quantity =  ps_stock_available.quantity - 1
INNER JOIN ps_product_attribute ON  ps_product_attribute.id_product_attribute = ps_stock_available.id_product_attribute
WHERE ps_product_attribute.ups = 01900000118;
```

But I always have this error:

```
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER
JOIN ps_product_attribute ON ps_product_attribute.id_product_attribute = p' at line 3
```

Someone can help me? I have try lot of different thing.

EDIT:
I have try a different way:

With a SELECT, I can have the id_product_attribute from ps_stock_available.

```
SELECT id_product_attribute
FROM ps_product_attribute
WHERE upc in ("01900000118","01900000119");
```

Does it possible to do an update with the result?

```
UPDATE  ps_stock_available
SET  quantity =  quantity-1
WHERE id_product_attribute in ("result1", "result2");
```

Comment: If that's a direct copy-paste, then there's probably something wrong in the query text that you can't see that's messing it up. If I had to guess, a zero-width or combining Unicode character. Try deleting the affected section and a bit around it, then retyping from scratch.

Comment: I don't have unicode character. I have try a lot of thing...I don't know what to do... :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution !

```
SELECT sa.id_product, sa.id_product_attribute, sa.quantity, pa.upc
FROM ps_stock_available AS sa
LEFT OUTER JOIN ps_product_attribute AS pa ON pa.id_product_attribute = sa.id_product_attribute
WHERE sa.id_product = 140;
```